# Prove $\forall k\geq 4,\log(1+x_k)-x_k\leq {-1\over6k}$ where $x_k={(-1)^k\over\sqrt k}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponentiation

**The question:**

> Prove $\forall k\geq 4,\log(1+x_k)-x_k\leq {-1\over6k}$ where $x_k={(-1)^k\over\sqrt k}$.

The above inequality holds iff $$\begin{align} &\log(1+x_k)\leq x_k-{1\over 6k}\\
&\Leftrightarrow 1+x_k\leq \exp (x_k-{1\over6k})
\end{align}$$
Using $$x+1\leq e^x$$we get $$x_k+1\leq e^{x_k}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$log(1+x) - x$ corresponds to the error of a first-order approximation of $log(1+x)$, so this will be least where the second (and higher) derivatives are least, which is on the positive side of 0. This means we can ignore the alternating signs and prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} - log(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}) \geq \frac{1}{6k}$.

The series for $log(1+x)$ is $x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - ...$, which means we must have $\frac{1}{2k} - \frac{1}{3k^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{4k^2} - ... \geq \frac{1}{6k}$, or $\frac{1}{3k} \geq \frac{1}{3k^{3/2}} - \frac{1}{4k^2} + ...$

But the RHS is less than $\frac{1}{3k^{3/2}}$ for any $k \geq 1$, so the inequality definitely holds in the required range.

Comment: Thank you. Why does ${1\over 3k^{3/2}}-{1\over 4k^2}+...<{1\over 3k^{3/2}}$?

Comment: If you subtract $\frac{1}{3k^{3/2}}$ from both sides, you can place the remaining terms into pairs containing a negative and positive term. As $k$ increases, the positive term in each pair decreases faster than the corresponding negative term because it has a larger exponent in the denominator, so all that remains is showing that the sum is negative for $k=1$, which is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x) = \log(1+x) - x + \frac 16 x^2$ for $-1 < x < 2$. We have 
$$
 f'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x} -1 + \frac 13 x = \frac{x(x-2)}{3(x+1)}
$$
so that $f$ is increasing on $(-1, 0)$ and decreasing on $(0, 2)$. As a consequence, the maximum of $f$ on the interval $(-1, 2)$ is $f(0) = 0$, i.e.
$$
 \log(1+x) - x \le -\frac 16 x^2 \, .
$$
Setting $x = x_k = \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt k}$ we get that
$$
 \log(1+x_k) - x_k \le -\frac{1}{6k}
$$
for $k \ge 2$.

Answer (score 1):

I will show that

$$\dfrac{1}{4k(1+1/\sqrt{2k})}
\lt x_{2k}-\log(1+x_{2k})
\lt \dfrac{1}{4k}
$$
and
$$\dfrac{1}{2(2k+1)}
\lt x_{2k+1}-\log(1+x_{2k+1})
\lt \dfrac{1}{2(2k+1)(1-1/\sqrt{2k+1})}
$$
which implies a stronger result.

$\sum_{k=0}^m t^k
=\dfrac{1-t^{m+1}}{1-t}
=\dfrac{1}{1-t}-\dfrac{t^{m+1}}{1-t}
$
so
$\dfrac{1}{1-t}
=\sum_{k=0}^m t^k+\dfrac{t^{m+1}}{1-t}
$.

Putting $-t$ for $t$,
$\frac{1}{1+t}
=\sum_{k=0}^m (-t)^k+\frac{(-1)^{m+1}t^{m+1}}{1+t}
$.

Integrating from $0$ to $x$,

$\begin{array}\\
\log(1+x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}\\
&=\int_0^x (\sum_{k=0}^m (-t)^k)dt+\int_0^x \dfrac{dt(-1)^{m+1}t^{m+1}}{1+t}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k\int_0^xt^kdt+(-1)^{m+1}\int_0^x \dfrac{t^{m+1}dt}{1+t}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+(-1)^{m+1}\int_0^x \dfrac{t^{m+1}dt}{1+t}\\
&= x-\int_0^x \dfrac{tdt}{1+t}
\qquad\text{putting } m=0\\
\end{array}
$

If $x > 0$ then

$\begin{array}\\
x-\log(1+x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{tdt}{1+t}\\
&\lt \int_0^x t\,dt\\
&=\dfrac{x^2}{2}\\
x-\log(1+x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{tdt}{1+t}\\
&\gt \int_0^x \dfrac{t\,dt}{1+x}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2}{2(1+x)}\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\dfrac{x^2}{2(1+x)}
\lt x-\log(1+x)
\lt \dfrac{x^2}{2}
$.

If $x < 0$ then

$\begin{array}\\
x-\log(1+x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{tdt}{1+t}\\
&=-\int_0^{-x} \dfrac{-tdt}{1-t}\\
&=\int_0^{-x} \dfrac{tdt}{1-t}\\
&<\int_0^{-x} \dfrac{tdt}{1+x}\\
&=\dfrac{(-x)^2}{2(1+x)}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2}{2(1-|x|)}\\
x-\log(1+x)
&=\int_0^{-x} \dfrac{tdt}{1-t}\\
&>\int_0^{-x} t\,dt\\
&=\dfrac{x^2}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\dfrac{x^2}{2}
\lt x-\log(1+x)
\lt \dfrac{x^2}{2(1-|x|)}
$.

We have
$x_k={(-1)^k\over\sqrt k}
$
so
$x_{2k}={1\over\sqrt {2k}}
$
and
$x_{2k+1}=-{1\over\sqrt {2k+1}}
$.

Note that
$x_k^2 = \dfrac1{k}$
so
$\dfrac{x_k^2}{2} = \dfrac1{2k}
$.

Therefore,

$\dfrac{1}{4k(1+1/\sqrt{2k})}
\lt x_{2k}-\log(1+x_{2k})
\lt \dfrac{1}{4k}
$
and
$\dfrac{1}{2(2k+1)}
\lt x_{2k+1}-\log(1+x_{2k+1})
\lt \dfrac{1}{2(2k+1)(1-1/\sqrt{2k+1})}
$.

Therefore
$\log(1+x_{2k})-x_{2k}
\lt -\dfrac{1}{4k(1+1/\sqrt{2k})}
$
and this is less than
$-\dfrac1{6(2k)}
$
if
$12 > 4(1+1/\sqrt{2k})$
or
$2 > 1/\sqrt{2k}$
which is always true.

Similarly,
$\log(1+x_{2k+1})-x_{2k+1}
\lt -\dfrac{1}{2(2k+1)}
$
and this is always less than
$-\dfrac{1}{6(2k+1)}
$.